# Проблема в выделение с регулярным выражением

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Стоит проблема в выделении слов в предложении. При этом это должно быть именно слово, а не подстрока другого. Так же оно может быть выделено другими символами вроде запятой или точки. Вот сама строка

*"Привет как дела ОНыв, не **ОН**, как го **ОНА** как понять что такое"*

Нужно выделить только слова **ОН** и **ОНА**.
Проблема в том что \b работает только для английских букв

[image: То как работает сейчас]

[image: Пример работы \b]

Comment: В каком ЯП? А то вдруг в вашем есть поддержка штук типа `\p{IsCyrillic}`… https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-classes-in-regular-expressions#unicode-category-or-unicode-block-p

Comment: Добавьте [опцию `/u`](https://regex101.com/r/Me5enI/1) в регулярное выражение, тогда будут поддерживаться все символы юникода.

Comment: @VadikSirekanyan буду благодарен, если допишете это в ответ.

Comment: Мне нужно для ECMA Script

Comment: Похоже, варианты [`(*UCP)`](https://regex101.com/r/mhFJ7r/1) и [`/u`](https://regex101.com/r/Bq7HhH/1) не работают для ECMAScript, нужно искать [другие решения](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10590098).